# How to exclude a property from being serialized in System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize() using a JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core

I want to be able to exclude a property when serializing using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer. I don't want to use a `JsonIgnore` attribute everywhere I want to do this. I would like to be able to define the properties I want to exclude during serialization only, via some kind of Fluent API, which currently does not exist.

The only option I was able to find is to define a `JsonConverter` and add it to the list of Converters on the `JsonSerializerOptions` that I pass to the Serialize() method like so:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new BookConverter());
json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(book, options);
```

In the JsonConverter I would have to write the entire JSON representation myself using a `Utf8JsonWriter`, excluding the property I don't want to serialize. This is a lot of work to just be able to exclude a property. While the JsonConverter is a great extensibility feature from the .NET team, its just too low-level for my use case. Does anyone know of any other way to acheive the exclusion of the property without having to write out the JSON representation myself?

I don't want to have to do the following:

- Use an attribute, or dynamically add an attribute at runtime
- Change the access modifier of the property to something like `private` or `protected`
- Use a 3rd party library, as my issue is solvable if I use Json.NET.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        // We want to serialize Book but to ignore the Author property
        var book = new Book() { Id = 1, Name = "Calculus", Author = new Author() };

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(book);
        // Default serialization, we get this:
        // json = { "Id": 1, "Name": "Calculus", "Author": {} }

        // Add our custom converter to options and pass it to the Serialize() method
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.Converters.Add(new BookConverter());
        json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(book, options);
        // I want to get this:
        // json = { Id: 1, Name: "Calculus" }
    }
}

public class Author { }

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class BookConverter : JsonConverter<Book>
{
    public override Book Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Use default implementation when deserializing (reading)
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Book>(ref reader, options);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Book value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Serializing. Here we have to write the JSON representation ourselves
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WriteNumber("Id", value.Id);
        writer.WriteString("Name", value.Name);
        // Don't write Author so we can exclude it

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I happened to stumble upon an article that demonstrates how to use the `JsonDocument` object in the new `System.Text.Json` namespace and it is the next best thing to a Fluent API. Here is how this question can be solved.

The BookConverter.Write() method:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Book value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value)))
    {
        foreach (var property in document.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
        {
            if (property.Name != "Author")
                property.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Comment: this works but the performance is not so good  if it should run fast. The `value` is serialized by the default way before being parsed into a `JsonDocument`, only then we can actually start serializing (with property ignoring supported) the value ourselves manually. So the execution cost is multiplied by almost 2-2.5 times.

Comment: I think this is a very bad idea as you also need to handle all of the custom stuff which is normally handled by the serializer, such as ignoring property that use `[JsonIgnore]` or perhaps have had their output name changed with `[JsonPropertyName("OptProperty")], this will also bump into other custom serializers causing them not to work.

Answer (score 12):

#### Option 1 - Cast to Interface

1. Extract interface which describes structure of desired object.

   ```cs
   public interface IBook
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Implement it on the original class `class Book : IBook`
3. Use the follow overload of `string Serialize(object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options = null);`

   ```cs
   json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(book, typeof(IBook), options);
   ```

   If you're serializing array of `Books` (plural), you'll need to pass `typeof(IEnumerable<IBook>)` as an argument.

#### Option 2 - Use AutoMapper

This is useful if you don't have access to the original `Book` class.

1. Create `LiteBook` class:

   ```cs
   public class LiteBook
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create mapping configuration:

   ```cs
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
       cfg.CreateMap<Book, LiteBook>();
   });
   ```
3. Map it and serialize

   ```
   json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Mapper(config).Map<LiteBook>(book), options)
   ```

Comment: What is the namespace of `MapperConfiguration`?

Answer (score 6):

.Net 7 made it possible to more flexibly and dynamically control which properties get serialized. See here for the official blog post:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#example-conditional-serialization

Answer (score 1):

You can simply ignore a property like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: I upvoted this because it does work even with circular self referencing, book > author > virtual book.  HOWEVER, the OP was very specific that this was NOT the answer he was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following method:

```
public static object ConvertToObjectWithoutListedProperties<T>(
                     this T objectToTransform,
                     string[] propertiesToIgnore)
{
    var type = objectToTransform.GetType();
    var returnClass = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        if (!propertiesToIgnore.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
            returnClass.Add(propertyInfo.Name,
                            propertyInfo.GetValue(objectToTransform));
    return returnClass;
}
```

**Credits**: "[Remove the null property from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987375/remove-the-null-property-from-object)"