# Choose class properties to include/exclude for JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0

Is there a way to specify which properties to include or exclude when Serializing a class using System.Text.Json.Serialization?

I know that there is the member attribute which I can use (`JsonIgnoreAttribute, JsonIgnoreCondition`). But I need a way to include some properties in some scenario and exclude other properties in another scenario.

For example:

- in scenario 'A' I need to **include** property `foo.name`
- in scenario 'B' I need to **exclude** property `foo.name`

JsonIgnoreAttribute will always exclude a property.
JsonIgnoreCondition is base on Property value.

In the Newtonsoft JSON library there is the `ContractResolver` that do this job. but I really wish to not use 2 JSon serialization engine in my project.

Comment: You can specify a condition on `JsonIgnore` via `JsonIgnoreCondition`. Ignore when the value is the `default` or `null`. Are you looking for these or your scenarios are more "dynamic"? If so, could you please elaborate on that part?

Comment: JsonIgnoreCondition is base the property value. I need a way to include or exclude properties base on the context.

Comment: In that case I think you have several options. 1) You can write multiple custom `JsonConverter`s and call the appropriate one when the condition is met. 2) Create a generic one, which accepts a list of property selector expressions. And serialize only those which are passed through the ctor.

Comment: 3) Use a [JsonDocument to iterate through the properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58566925/13268855) and do the branching inside the converter. It is only viable if you can pass the context to the converter.

Comment: That look great, I'll try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record

As Peter Csala suggested, I ended up using `JsonConverter`
It work perfectly with what I need.

The concept is:

```
public class BaseTypeOnlyConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        var t = value.GetType();

        var propertiesName = t.GetProperties()
            .Where(o => ShouldInclude(o))
            .Select(o => o.Name.ToLower())
            .ToList();

        using (var document = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value)))
        {
            foreach (var property in document.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                if (propertiesName.Contains(property.Name.ToLower()))
                    property.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    private bool ShouldInclude(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
          //Do checkup ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I like also to share this link that was use has example: https://www.thinktecture.com/en/asp-net/aspnet-core-3-0-custom-jsonconverter-for-the-new-system_text_json/

Comment: Also here I related article that I didn't find before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566735/how-to-exclude-a-property-from-being-serialized-in-system-text-json-jsonserializ?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can edit your own post to extend it with further information. BTW the SO link in your 2nd comment is the same as I've shared with you in my 3rd comment on your question. :D