# Ignore null values when saving data in CosmosDb with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I use CosmosDb with the Entity Framework. I need that when saving data if one of the properties is `null`, it is stored as `undefined`.
Is there any option to initialize `DbContext` from `CosmosClient`, or set `CosmosSerializationOptions`?

I tried the following option, but it does not work for me:

```NET
context.Database.GetCosmosClient().ClientOptions.SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions()
{
     IgnoreNullValues = true
};
```

The option without using EF is working:

```NET
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey)
   .WithSerializerOptions(new CosmosSerializationOptions() { IgnoreNullValues = true })
   .Build();
```

```JSON
//The current result
{
    "Id": "fad8b443-6d10-4009-853c-efb6aac18031",
    "Discriminator": "User",
    "FirstName": "Charley",
    "LastName": null
}
//Expected result
{
    "Id": "fad8b443-6d10-4009-853c-efb6aac18031",
    "Discriminator": "User",
    "FirstName": "Charley"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using Entity Framework in my code, but in searching for the right way to get Cosmos to ignore null values, I found an alternative solution that may work for you.

I was inspired by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net) to add a `JsonProperty` attribute with `ItemNullValueHandling` set to `NullValueHandling.Ignore` for the classes I'm saving, like so:

```
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "bar")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "baz")]
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

async void Main()
{
    Foo f = new Foo() { Id = "1", Bar = "bar" };
    string azureSqlCoreApiPrimaryKey = "[REDACTED]";
    string azureSqlCoreApiUrl = "[REDACTED]";
    string cosmosDbName = "[REDACTED]";
    string cosmosContainerName = "test";
    CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(azureSqlCoreApiUrl, azureSqlCoreApiPrimaryKey);
    var cosmosDb = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(cosmosDbName);
    var cosmosContainer = cosmosDb.GetContainer(cosmosContainerName);
    
    await cosmosContainer.CreateItemAsync(f);
}
```

In my tests, the document would have a null 'baz' attribute if and only if I commented out the `JsonObject` property.

The accepted answer to that question suggests that you modify the options on a `JsonSerializer` object instead of touching each class you're trying to save. This is analogous to how you tried to modify the serialization options on your `CosmosClient`, but were ultimately unable to do so. I ended up moving to modifying the `CosmosClient` serialization options myself, as you demonstrated. But in a case where you can't modify the serialization options, but you can modify the class you're writing, this is a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the sample and I found it really has no option to set `IgnoreNullValues` when initialize the client, and here's the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#cosmos-options):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(
                "https://xxx.documents.azure.com:443/",
                "primary key",
                databaseName: "Tasks",
                options => {
                    options.SerializerOptions(....);//there's no property choice to set
                });
```

[image]

According to this situation, what you can do is modify the entity, such as removing the null property, and I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987375/remove-the-null-property-from-object) in st, I think you can refer to it. And if your entity always exists null value in some specific property(e.g one property 'userConf' may be a null property, you can create another entity without this property), you can even create another entity to meet your requirement.

Comment: I am all ears for a direct solution to set 'IgnoreNullValues = true ', I really can't find it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do this with CosmosDbContextOptionsBuilder in the UseCosmos method.
The SerializerOptions property is available from under the DbContext object.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Yes, I see, I just wanna show there's no option for SerializerOptions, so I can't set this property when call 'UseCosmos', and I also tried to find the place to set it. If there's exactly nowhere to set, that means what I said is right. Thanks sir!